# Run Kubernetes Job on network request (aka socket-based activation)

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a server nodes and powerful expensive worker nodes.
Worker nodes are set to be autoscaled from/to zero and run few hours per week.

When server creates HTTP request to worker Service (where corresponding Job resides on worker nodes) I want that worker node to bring up, start Job pod and process this request. Something similar to systemd service socket-based activation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to create your own Custom Resource Definition (CRD) and write the trigger you need.

You may find useful this link:  https://kubeless.io/docs/implementing-new-trigger/